# Javascript / jQuery - Problems with string to Float and .toFixed()

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with a function who gets a parameter as string
and now i want to make the string to a float (cause its not an integer)

```
function(costsForThisPlayer){
    moneyRemaining += costsForThisPlayer;               
    moneyRemaining2Decimals = parseFloat(moneyRemaining).toFixed(2); 
}
```

in my example now, my costsForThisplayer was "1.0"

but now my moneyRemaining looks like this:

991.00

before my moneyRemaining was 99

so my code only appends the value to the end of nr instead of adding the value ?!?!?!

does anyone have an idea?

I thought

- converting to float
- and then make the moneyRemaining with toFixed() with 2 decimal places

but it doenst work

EDIT:

This is my whole **js code**

```
 function addGoalkeeperByClickEvent(playerName, id, costsForThisPlayer) {
$(document).off('click', '.goalKepperRow, .goalkeeperGreyRow').on('click', '.goalKepperRow, .goalkeeperGreyRow', function() {

  $('#goalkeeperLine div p').first().parent().html("<div id='"+id+"' costsForThisPlayer='"+costsForThisPlayer+"'><img src='https://d34h6ikdffho99.cloudfront.net/uploads/real_team/shirt/1188/shirt-333.svg'><span class='ui-icon  ui-icon-circle-close remove' style='top: -69.0833px; left: 34.3167px;'></span><div>".concat(playerName));


    console.log("GK wurde mit Row Click entfernt:");

    $(this).attr('class', 'goalKepperRow');
    GoalKeeperQuantity--;
    totalPlayersOnField--;


    moneyRemaining += costsForThisPlayer;
    moneyRemaining2Decimals = parseFloat(moneyRemaining).toFixed(2);                  
    $("#moneyRemaining").html(moneyRemaining2Decimals+" $ (Mio)");   


    $("#moneyRemaining").html(moneyRemaining2Decimals+" $ (Mio)");    

    console.log("bis hier hin gehts");

    $("#field #".concat($(this).attr('id'))).empty();
    $("#field #".concat($(this).attr('id'))).parent().html("<p></p>");

    $("#players").html(totalPlayersOnField+" / 12");      
});
```

};

Comment: applying toFixed on a parseInt() has no effect because integer do not have a decimal point, either you should use a parseFloat,  Again apply parseFloat on costsForThisPlayer because its also treated as String.

Comment: @ClainDsilva sorry i edited my 1st post, i tried it with parseFloat() and THIS was the thing which not worked sorry for misunderstanding...

so what else could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply parseFloat on costsForThisPlayer to make both of the type Float to perform an addition.

```
    function(costsForThisPlayer){
      moneyRemaining = parseFloat(moneyRemaining) + parseFloat(costsForThisPlayer);
      //use moneyRemaining.toFixed(2) on remaining code                         
   }
```

Comment: @Andreas am assuming  moneyRemaining is of type float, else  apply parseFloat to it as well, I have made both of type float, see the updated answer

Comment: @Andreas correct, I see your point , fixes applied to the code

Comment: thank you so much for your help but i dont know how I can use this solution :( exactly

Comment: ok got it ;) hahah

your solution helped me and i posted my code into a new answer!

have a good one ;)

Comment: @nbg15 glad that it helped

Answer (score 0):

ok this is my code now ;)

```
moneyRemaining += parseFloat(costsForThisPlayer);
moneyRemaining2Decimals = moneyRemaining.toFixed(2);                  
$("#moneyRemaining").html(moneyRemaining2Decimals+" $ (Mio)");
```